# Not saving to database, Spring Boot, Hibernate, PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, mustache

Spring Boot 3.0.0 application, after filling out the form and submitting it, the input field is cleared, but saving to the corresponding database table does not occur. There are no errors in the log.

Model

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String text;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
import kz.onlineshelter.helppet.model.Message;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {}
```

Controller

```
import kz.onlineshelter.helppet.model.Message;
import kz.onlineshelter.helppet.repository.MessageRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public class AppController {
    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AppController(MessageRepository messageRepository) {
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String message(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepository.findAll();

        model.put("messages", messages);

        return "message";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String add(@RequestParam String text, Map<String, Object> model) {
        Message message = new Message(text);

        messageRepository.save(message);

        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepository.findAll();

        model.put("messages", messages);

        return "message";
    }
}
```

Application

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelppetApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(HelppetApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

resources/templates/message.mustache

```
<html>

<body>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter your text" /><br>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>List of messages</div>
{{#messages}}
    <div>
        <span>{{text}}</span>
    </div>
{{/messages}}
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/***
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>***</groupId>
   <artifactId>helppet</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>***</name>
   <description>***</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

log file

```
"C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJDK-17\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63010:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\bin" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\java projects\helppet\target\classes;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.2\spring-aop-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.9.1\aspectjweaver-1.9.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.0.2\spring-jdbc-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.1.5.Final\hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.19\byte-buddy-1.12.19.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.1\jaxb-runtime-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.1\jaxb-core-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\1.0.0\angus-activation-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.1\txw2-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.0\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.10.1\antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.0.0\spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.0.0\spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.0.2\spring-orm-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.2\spring-context-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.0.2\spring-tx-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.2\spring-beans-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.4\slf4j-api-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.0.2\spring-aspects-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mustache\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-mustache-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.5\logback-classic-1.4.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.5\logback-core-1.4.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.19.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.19.0\log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.4\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.33\snakeyaml-1.33.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\samskivert\jmustache\1.15\jmustache-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-web-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-json-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.14.1\jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.14.1\jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.14.1\jackson-core-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.14.1\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.14.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.14.1\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.0.2\spring-web-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.10.2\micrometer-observation-1.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.10.2\micrometer-commons-1.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.0.2\spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.2\spring-expression-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\3.0.0\spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.0.0\spring-boot-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.0.0\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.5.1\postgresql-42.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.1\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.1\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.1\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.0\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.2\spring-core-6.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.2\spring-jcl-6.0.2.jar" kz.onlineshelter.helppet.HelppetApplication
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.0)

2022-12-22T10:18:07.901+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] k.o.***.***Application                   : Starting ***Application using Java 17.0.4.1 with PID 8316 (*:\***\***\target\classes started by Admin in *:\***\***)
2022-12-22T10:18:07.903+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] k.o.***.***Application                   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-22T10:18:07.944+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-12-22T10:18:07.944+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-12-22T10:18:08.400+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-22T10:18:08.435+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 30 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-22T10:18:08.807+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-22T10:18:08.815+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-22T10:18:08.815+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
2022-12-22T10:18:08.861+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-22T10:18:08.861+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 917 ms
2022-12-22T10:18:08.950+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-22T10:18:09.038+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@54ef2cef
2022-12-22T10:18:09.039+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-12-22T10:18:09.070+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-12-22T10:18:09.110+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
2022-12-22T10:18:09.232+03:00  WARN 8316 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2022-12-22T10:18:09.344+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-12-22T10:18:09.824+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-12-22T10:18:09.830+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-22T10:18:10.004+03:00  WARN 8316 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-12-22T10:18:10.234+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-12-22T10:18:10.256+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-12-22T10:18:10.265+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [  restartedMain] k.o.helppet.HelppetApplication           : Started HelppetApplication in 2.768 seconds (process running for 4.113)
2022-12-22T10:18:13.951+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-22T10:18:13.952+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-22T10:18:13.954+03:00  INFO 8316 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

After starting the application, the corresponding table in the database is successfully created

I added an annotation @Repository into Repository, added an annotation @Transactional into Controller in add method, into the signature of the same method added an anotation @ResponseBody but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You need to introduce a **transactional** `Service` layer between the controller and the repository. Nice article about it: https://www.codeusingjava.com/boot/trans/1

Comment: Thanks for the help, I implemented receiving all messages and saving new ones through services, receiving all messages is successful, but saving new messages to the database still does not work and the log is also empty